# Removing an list element which has "KA" substring, but not all elements are removed. Why?

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to remove every element from the list that has "KA" sub string but when i tried to do so, it was not working properly.

```py
def removeKA(reg_list):
    for reg_no in reg_list:
        if "KA" in reg_no:
            reg_list.remove(reg_no)
            print(reg_no)

reg_list = ["KA09 3056","KA12 9098","MH10 6776","GJ01 7854","KL07 4332"]
removeKA(reg_list)
```

No error messages were encountered. But Output should be 
KA09 3056
KA12 9098

But instead of that i am getting output as
KA09 3056

Comment: you shouldn't modify a list as you are iterating it, it causes the iteration to skip some elements (as they are "shifted left" after deletion of previous element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2):

Just use comprehension:

```
def removeKA(reg_list):
    return [i for i in reg_list if 'KA' not in i]

reg_list = ["KA09 3056","KA12 9098","MH10 6776","GJ01 7854","KL07 4332"]
removeKA(reg_list)

['MH10 6776', 'GJ01 7854', 'KL07 4332']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the you are printing `reg_no` and not the list. The element is getting removed from the list though. Although, this is not the correct way to do the same.

```
def removeKA(reg_list):
for reg_no in reg_list:
    if "KA" in reg_no:

        # The element is removed below
        reg_list.remove(reg_no)

        # But the value still exists inside reg_no
        print(reg_no)
```

Comment: No, the element is not removed from list either, only 1 element is removed instead of 2.